# PDDL predicate variable with multiple types

Tags: pddl

I am trying to write a PDDL domain. I have 4 types.
My issues is that when specifiying one of the predicates:

```
At(?x - type ?l - location)
```

I want x to be able to take on three of the types, but it only allows me to do one. What should I do?

Comment: Your PDDL domain is incomplete, and you should join the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The [syntax of PDDL](http://pddl4j.imag.fr/repository/wiki/BNF-PDDL-3.1.pdf) expects your predicate declaration to look as follows:

```
(at ?x - entity ?l - location)
```

Check closely the use of parentheses.

Otherwise, you are doing it right.
By expecting an `entity` that is a supertype of `agent`, `object` and `robot`, you will accept any of these subtypes.

However note that in many planners, the type `object` is already implicitly defined as the root type. I recommend you rename it into `physical_object`.

Comment: thanks for the syntax documentation! the issue was that i did not know how to declare *supertypes* if that makes sense

Answer (score -1):

Okay so essentially what I did was I created a type called entity and then specififed that my robot, agent and object types are entities:

```
        (:types
    entity
    agent - entity
    object - entity
    robot - entity
    location
    )

(:predicates
At(?x - entity, ?l - location)
)
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You should have edited your question instead.